# what are the modes of the given data set

Tags: statistics

consider the given data set

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
  class & frequency \\
\hline
0-10 &4   \\
\hline
10-20 &10  \\
\hline
20-30 &10   \\
\hline
30-40 &10   \\
\hline
40-50 &6  \\
\hline
50-60 &4  \\
\hline
\end{array}

I know the formula $$Mode=l+h(\frac{f_m-f_1}{2f_m-f_1-f_2})$$

but this table has three mode classes

how to proceed

my prooblem is what are the modes? how to use the formula to this problem? (since formula gives dividing by zero)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When modal class is repeated, Mode cannot be estimated directly using the formula you quoted. Instead use the following formula for such cases:

$$Z = 3M - 2\bar{X}$$

where $Z$ is the mode, $M$ is the Median and $\bar{X}$ is the Mean.

Comment: so, if mode class repeated only two times can I use the formula I quoted?

Comment: @BadEnglish yes. you can use it whenever mode class is repeated more than once.